# jQuery Mobile Listview in Popup Selected Item Not Highlighted

Tags: ipad, listview, jquery-mobile, safari

I am seeing some odd behavior with a JQM listview in a popup on Safari on an iPad.  It's an iPad 2 with iOS 8.2.

The listview has data-filter="true".  When a listitem is touched the item isn't highlighted as selected and focus is immediately sent back to the filter text box and the listview scrolls back to the top.  You can see [a demo of the strange behavior here](http://australian-coins.com/mobile/job-popup-test.ht).  This is the only real code on the page:

```
        <a href="#job-popup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Show Job Popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="job-popup" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all ui-content" data-dismissible="false">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a job" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Choose a job</li>
            <li><a href="#">1001 Job 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1002 Job 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1003 Job 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1001 Job 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1002 Job 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1003 Job 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1001 Job 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1002 Job 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1003 Job 9</a></li>
        </ul>


    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-e" id="btn-select-job">Select Job</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" id="btn-cancel-select-job">Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->

</div>
```

On other devices the listitem is highlighted as selected and focus is not placed back onto the filter text box.  My question is why is Safari behaving in this manner and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: Try $("#job-popup").on("click", "a", function(e){  return false; });

Comment: Unfortunately no luck.  I've tried preventDefault too but that didn't work either.  I've decided to manually highlight the selected item (addClass('ui-btn-e') and put up with the scrolling.  At least it's obvious what list item is selected.